# Migrating from Angular 1.2.19 to 1.3.0-beta.15 using new Controller as declaration not working

Tags: angularjs

I am migrating a simple example I have which work and uses angular 1.2.19. So the following works:

index.html fragment:

```
<html ng-app="MyApp">
...
<form ng-controller="MyController" ng-submit="talkToMe()">
        <label>Name:</label> 
        <input type="text" ng-model="name"  placeholder="Enter a name here" required>
        <hr />
        <h3>Almighty AngularJS Function Answer:  {{answer}}</h3>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" value="Talk to Me">Talk to Me</button>
</form>
```

and the js controller:

'use strict';

```
(function() {
    var myApp = angular.module('MyApp', []);

    myApp.controller('MyController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
        $scope.name = '';
        $scope.answer = '';
        $scope.talkToMe = function(){

            $scope.answer = "Hello great master " + $scope.name + ", may the force be with you!";
            //reset the input field
            $scope.name = '';
        };
    } ]);
})();
```

Than I have an upgraded version 1.3.0-beta.15 where I try using the "Controller as" notation, but this doesn't work, what am I missing???

1.3 implementation:

```
<html ng-app="MyApp">

....

<form ng-controller="MyController as myCtrl" ng-submit="myCtrl.talktoMe()">
        <label>Name:</label> 
        <input type="text" ng-model="myCtrl.name"  placeholder="Enter a name here" required>
        <hr />
        <h3>Almighty AngularJS Function Answer:  {{myCtrl.answer}}</h3>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" value="Talk to Me">Talk to Me</button>
</form>
```

and the js controller:

```
'use strict';
(function() {
    var myApp = angular.module('MyApp', []);

    myApp.controller('MyController', ['$http', function($http) {
        this.name = '';
        this.answer = '';
        this.talkToMe = function(){
            this.answer = "Hello great master " + this.name + ", may the force be with you!";
            //reset the input field
            this.name = '';
        };
    } ]);
})();
```

Comment: code works fine here http://plnkr.co/edit/slNAoyMkkFutivqCY6Ji?p=preview  Have you oversimplified example of what's not working?

Comment: Hi @charlietfl - I got back to this with a fresh mind. It turns out that was only a typo on the call myCtrl.talktoMe() (see the lower case T) . Your example definitely helped me find the problem. Thank you.